# I2C peripheral fails after a single transaction

Tags: i2c, c, microprocessor, beaglebone-black, real-time

I am using [this](https://github.com/LinuxDroneLab/pru-i2c-lib) library to sample some sensors over the I2C bus using the PRUs on the Beaglebone Black.

It seems as if only the first transaction works correctly, after which the library seems to only attempt to read from register address 0xFF, followed by the SCL line being pulled low (see attached image captures by logic analyzer). I have already opened an issue on their github, but am not expecting an answer there as the repository hasn't been updated in years and the author hasn't been active on GitHub since 2019.

[image: Signal Analyzer Output]

While trying to find the problem myself, I decided to write the register address and received data in the shared memory to inspect using prudebug. For this test, I am attempting to read registers 0x00 and 0x03. Interestingly, it writes the correct register addresses into memory (see image), but only the first returned value is correct (0xEA). The value written into the received data buffer in shared memory is 0xFF, which does not make sense. As can be seen from the logic analyzer, 0xFF is the address it attempts to read from.

[image: Memory analysis]

I don't know what I am doing wrong here, but any help would be appreciated! My main code is shown below, and the library functions can be found in the linked repository [here](https://github.com/LinuxDroneLab/pru-i2c-lib/blob/master/pru_i2c_driver.c).

```
uint8_t curr_data_idx = 0;
uint8_t tmp = 0;
uint8_t reg = 0x00;
volatile uint8_t * buf = ((volatile uint8_t*)(RESERVED_SMEM_ADDR + 32));

int main(void)
{

    // enable OCP
    CT_CFG.SYSCFG_bit.STANDBY_INIT = 0;

    pru_i2c_driver_DelayMicros(500000);

    uint8_t res = 0;
    res = pru_i2c_driver_Init(1);
    uint8_t saddr = 0x68;

    pru_i2c_driver_ReadReg(1, saddr, reg, &tmp);
    buf[curr_data_idx] = tmp;
    pru_i2c_driver_DelayMicros(1000);
    curr_data_idx++;

    reg = 0x03;
    pru_i2c_driver_ReadReg(1, saddr, reg, &tmp);
    buf[curr_data_idx] = tmp;
    pru_i2c_driver_DelayMicros(1000);
    curr_data_idx++;
   
    __halt();
    return 0;
}
```

The Technical Reference Manual of the CPU and the I2C peripheral can be found [here](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spruh73q/spruh73q.pdf), page 4583.

Comment: Well, that's what may happen when you fetch a random piece of the code from the net. Have you debugged where and why it fails to work as expected? On the other hand, the logic analyzer cannot show if the problem is in the analog bus waveforms. You should at least post the schematics and which chips you communicate and how you wired them to rule out hardware issues. But since all the library does is to wait until bytes are transferred out, it's quite useless itself. You could just bit-bang the I2C bus with GPIO and delays and it would take exactly same amount of time at same I2C clock speed.

Comment: Would [TI Designs Enhanced I2C and SMBus Master Interface Reference Design With PRU-ICSS](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tiduby1a/tiduby1a.pdf) help to provide an alternative library? While that TI design was created for a TMDSIDK437X, the AM437x that uses the same _Programmable Real-time Unit and Industrial Communication Subsystem (PRU-ICSS)_ as in the AM335x used on the Beaglebone Black.

Comment: @ChesterGillon thats a very useful link, thank you for sharing

Comment: @Justme I have indeed found the root of the error now, the issue was indeed poorly written software on the library's side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the issue with the given code after some tedious debugging; turns out the delays given in the library were not enough, and the library failed to clear the bit flags that indicate an error occurred. As a result, the first transaction would occur as normal, but when attempting to read the data from the RX FIFO, the AERR flag would be set since the FIFO was still empty when trying to read due to the delays not being enough. Then, when trying to perform the second read, the error flag is still set and the data read from the RX FIFO is actually the previous value. After adding a few more microseconds of delay between transactions and making sure to handle any errors that occur everything works well. The updated ReadBytes function from the library I've rewritten to:

```
uint8_t pru_i2c_driver_ReadBytes(
                  const uint8_t i2cDevice, 
                  const uint8_t address, 
                  const uint8_t reg, 
                  const uint8_t bytes, 
                  uint8_t* buffer, 
                  i2c_flags_t* flags
)
{
    uint8_t tries = 0;
_init_section:
    if(!pru_i2c_initialized[i2cDevice-1]) {
        if(!pru_i2c_driver_Init(i2cDevice)) {
            *flags |= I2C_FAILED_INIT;
            if(tries++ < MAX_TRIES){
                pru_i2c_driver_DelayMicros(1);
                goto _init_section;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
    tries = 0;

_write_init:
    if (!pru_i2c_driver_WaitBB(i2cDevice))
    {
        *flags |= I2C_FAILED_WAIT_BB;
        if(tries++ < MAX_TRIES){
            pru_i2c_driver_DelayMicros(1);
            goto _write_init;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    tries = 0;

    CT_I2C[i2cDevice-1]->I2C_SA_bit.I2C_SA_SA = address; // 7 bit address
    CT_I2C[i2cDevice-1]->I2C_CNT_bit.I2C_CNT_DCOUNT = 1; // 1 byte to transmit
    CT_I2C[i2cDevice-1]->I2C_CON = 0x8601; // EN/MST/TRX/STT
    pru_i2c_driver_DelayMicros(7);


_write_start:
    if (!pru_i2c_driver_WaitXRDY(i2cDevice))
    {
        *flags |= I2C_FAILED_WAIT_XRDY;
        if(tries++ < MAX_TRIES){
            pru_i2c_driver_DelayMicros(1);
            goto _write_start;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    // write register to read
    CT_I2C[i2cDevice-1]->I2C_DATA = reg;
    CT_I2C[i2cDevice-1]->I2C_IRQSTATUS_RAW_bit.I2C_IRQSTATUS_RAW_XRDY = 0b1;

    // wait access to registers
    if (!pru_i2c_driver_WaitARDY(i2cDevice))
    {
        *flags |= I2C_FAILED_WAIT_ARDY;
        if(tries++ < MAX_TRIES){
            pru_i2c_driver_DelayMicros(1);
            goto _write_start;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    pru_i2c_driver_DelayMicros(5);
    CT_I2C[i2cDevice-1]->I2C_IRQSTATUS_RAW_bit.I2C_IRQSTATUS_RAW_ARDY = 0b1;

    if (CT_I2C[i2cDevice-1]->I2C_IRQSTATUS_RAW_bit.I2C_IRQSTATUS_RAW_AERR)
    {
        *flags |= I2C_AERR_WRITE;
        if(tries++ < MAX_TRIES){
            pru_i2c_driver_DelayMicros(1);
            goto _write_start;
        }
        *flags |= I2C_AERR_WRITE_UNRESOLVED;
        return 0;
    }
    if(CT_I2C[i2cDevice-1]->I2C_IRQSTATUS_RAW_bit.I2C_IRQSTATUS_RAW_NACK)
    {
        *flags |= I2C_NACK_DETECTED;
        CT_I2C[i2cDevice-1]->I2C_IRQSTATUS_RAW_bit.I2C_IRQSTATUS_RAW_NACK = 0b1;
        return 0;
    }

    tries = 0;
_read_init:
    // read data
    CT_I2C[i2cDevice-1]->I2C_CNT_bit.I2C_CNT_DCOUNT = bytes; // bytes to receive
    CT_I2C[i2cDevice-1]->I2C_CON = 0x8403; // EN/MST/STP/STT
    pru_i2c_driver_DelayMicros(20);

_read_start:
    // wait data
    if (!pru_i2c_driver_WaitRRDY(i2cDevice))
    {
        *flags |= I2C_FAILED_WAIT_RRDY;
        if(tries++ < MAX_TRIES){
            pru_i2c_driver_DelayMicros(1);
            goto _read_start;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    pru_i2c_driver_DelayMicros(10);

    int8_t count;

    for (count = 0; count < bytes; count++)
    {
    _looptop:
        // read byte
        buffer[count] = CT_I2C[i2cDevice-1]->I2C_DATA;

        pru_i2c_driver_DelayMicros(10);

        if (CT_I2C[i2cDevice-1]->I2C_IRQSTATUS_RAW_bit.I2C_IRQSTATUS_RAW_AERR)
        {
            CT_I2C[i2cDevice-1]->I2C_IRQSTATUS_RAW_bit.I2C_IRQSTATUS_RAW_AERR = 0b1;
            if(tries++ < MAX_TRIES){
                pru_i2c_driver_DelayMicros(10);
                goto _looptop;
            }
            return 0;

        }
        if (CT_I2C[i2cDevice-1]->I2C_IRQSTATUS_RAW_bit.I2C_IRQSTATUS_RAW_NACK)
        {
            *flags |= I2C_NACK_DETECTED;
            CT_I2C[i2cDevice-1]->I2C_IRQSTATUS_RAW_bit.I2C_IRQSTATUS_RAW_NACK = 0b1;
            return 0;
        }

    _wait_next_data:
        // require next data
        CT_I2C[i2cDevice-1]->I2C_IRQSTATUS_RAW_bit.I2C_IRQSTATUS_RAW_RRDY = 0b1;

        // wait data
        if (!pru_i2c_driver_WaitRRDY(i2cDevice))
        {
            *flags |= I2C_FAILED_WAIT_RRDY;
            if(tries++ < MAX_TRIES){
                pru_i2c_driver_DelayMicros(10);
                goto _wait_next_data;
            }
            return 0;
        }

        tries = 0;
    }

_transaction_end:
    // wait for access ready
    if (!pru_i2c_driver_WaitARDY(i2cDevice))
    {
        *flags |= I2C_FAILED_WAIT_ARDY;
        if(tries++ < MAX_TRIES){
            pru_i2c_driver_DelayMicros(10);
            goto _transaction_end;
        }
        return 0;
    }

_wait_bus_free:
    // wait for bus free
    // wait data
    if (!pru_i2c_driver_WaitBF(i2cDevice))
    {
        *flags |= I2C_FAILED_WAIT_BF;
        if(tries++ < MAX_TRIES){
            pru_i2c_driver_DelayMicros(10);
            goto _wait_bus_free;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    CT_I2C[i2cDevice-1]->I2C_IRQSTATUS_RAW_bit.I2C_IRQSTATUS_RAW_ARDY = 0b1;
    CT_I2C[i2cDevice-1]->I2C_IRQSTATUS_RAW_bit.I2C_IRQSTATUS_RAW_XRDY = 0b1;
    CT_I2C[i2cDevice-1]->I2C_IRQSTATUS_RAW_bit.I2C_IRQSTATUS_RAW_RRDY = 0b1;

    return count;
}
```

Furthermore, the delay function was plain wrong. It did not delay the requested microseconds and was optimized away by the compiler as soon as optimizations were turned on. I fixed it by changing it to:

```
void DelayMicros(uint8_t micros){
    // Factor of 29 gives most accurate timings verified with logic analyzer
    uint16_t cycles = ((uint16_t)micros * 29u);
    uint16_t i = 0;
#pragma MUST_ITERATE(29, , 29)
#pragma UNROLL(1)
    for (i = 0; i < cycles; i++)
    {
        __delay_cycles(1);
    };
}
```

Comment: Just for completeness, I added a comment to the github issue [Only the first transaction works #1](https://github.com/LinuxDroneLab/pru-i2c-lib/issues/1#issuecomment-1867701578) to link to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be your code. The best thing would to put an oscilloscope on it and verify the logic levels. Check the logic levels of both I2C parts. You may have too much capacitance on the lines which can affect the rise times. If the rise times are too slow, the I2C bus can have errant bits.